# Reset the "Auto open form for single feature results"

Tags: qgis-3, vector

Is there a way to remove the setting "Auto open form for single feature results" in QGIS 3.10?

Answer (score 1):

To change the behaviour of Identify feature tool just go in the Identify Results Tab and turn off the option "Auto open form for single feature results" as shown in the image.

[image]